# gem update doesn't work

Tags: ruby, windows, openssl, rubygems

I am attempting to get ruby to run. My company uses a proxy server: http://proxy.hitachi-id.com:80

And I am using precompiled ruby.

I can add a source, but I cannot run `gem update` without a failure.

```
(inst1) (robotframework-Rs4th6sJ) Administrator@DANIE01-ROB1 Z:\Users\danie01\fox\test\watir
# gem sources --add http://rubygems.org
https://rubygems.org is recommended for security over http://rubygems.org

Do you want to add this insecure source? [yn]  y
http://rubygems.org added to sources

(inst1) (robotframework-Rs4th6sJ) Administrator@DANIE01-ROB1 Z:\Users\danie01\fox\test\watir
# gem update --system
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: tlsv1 alert protocol version (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

I followed https://bundler.io/v1.16/guides/rubygems_tls_ssl_troubleshooting_guide.html

Which says I need to run the following command:

```
ruby -ropen-uri -e 'eval open("https://git.io/vQhWq").read'
```

But this command fails.

If I do:

```
Administrator@DANIE01-ROB1 C:\Users\Administrator
# set https_proxy=https://proxy.hitachi-id.com:80
```

I get:

```
Administrator@DANIE01-ROB1 C:\Users\Administrator
# ruby -ropen-uri -e 'eval open("https://git.io/vQhWq").read'
C:/ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:249:in `open_http': Non-HTTP proxy URI: https://proxy.hitachi-id.com:80 (RuntimeError)
        from C:/ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:775:in `buffer_open'
        from C:/ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:203:in `block in open_loop'
        from C:/ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:201:in `catch'
        from C:/ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:201:in `open_loop'
        from C:/ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:146:in `open_uri'
        from C:/ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:677:in `open'
        from C:/ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:33:in `open'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

And if I do:

```
Administrator@DANIE01-ROB1 C:\Users\Administrator
# set https_proxy=http://proxy.hitachi-id.com:80
```

I get:

```
Administrator@DANIE01-ROB1 C:\Users\Administrator
# ruby -ropen-uri -e 'eval open("https://git.io/vQhWq").read'
C:/ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
        from C:/ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `block in connect'
        from C:/ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:54:in `timeout'
        from C:/ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:99:in `timeout'
        from C:/ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `connect'
        from C:/ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:755:in `do_start'
        from C:/ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:744:in `start'
        from C:/ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:306:in `open_http'
        from C:/ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:775:in `buffer_open'
        from C:/ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:203:in `block in open_loop'
        from C:/ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:201:in `catch'
        from C:/ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:201:in `open_loop'
        from C:/ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:146:in `open_uri'
        from C:/ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:677:in `open'
        from C:/ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:33:in `open'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What's your exact Ruby patchlevel (`ruby -v`)?

Comment: Note that you can manually download https://git.io/vQhWq , save it to disk, and run it yourself.

Comment: Have you read/followed the official documentation relating to this SSL error? https://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update/#installing-using-update-packages

Comment: It looks like your proxy server isn't set up to correctly handle HTTPS traffic, or it has invalid certificates.